# Which USB boot selection do I use?

Tags: usb

I have Ubuntu burned onto a USB and when i enter into my bios it gives me 4 different options for usb- Zip, FDD, CD ROM , and HDD. Which one would i use?

Comment: Only the option that includes the word "USB" is a USB option. FDD is a floppy disc drive, CD ROM is a CD drive, and HDD is a hard drive.

Comment: None of my options only say USB. They are all followed up by something.

Comment: I said, "only use the option that includes the word 'USB'," not, "use the option that includes only 'USB'." :)

Comment: Well now i know I need to learn how to read again. Thanks for the help xD

Comment: See this link: [help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick/bootUSB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick/bootUSB)

Comment: For me ``ÙSD-HDD``` worked only.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience, either `USB-FDD` or `USB-HDD` is what you want to choose. I believe it depends on how the flash drive is formatted. `FAT32` and any derivatives or similar ones (ie, `exFAT` and `FAT`) will probably be the `USB-FDD` option, while `NTFS` and `EXT` formatted flash drives will boot when the `USB-HDD` option is selected.

This is something that I often test multiple times. If one doesn't work, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> to reset before the main OS boots, then try another one.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with `usb-Zip` as you want to boot from a usb.