# Not getting option to Boot with USB in Boot Options

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, live-usb

I'm trying in dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 on my HP Pavilion G6 laptopn running Windows 10 Pro. In Boot options I'm not finding the option to Boot from USB in my Boot options. I've done the following:
Was following the instructions from the below URL:
https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/

1. Disable Secure and Legacy Boot from BIOS and disable fast startup from power options.
2. Downloaded Ubuntu 16.04 desktop ISO file and created an image in my USB using Rufus 3.10 with MBR partition scheme(the only option available).
3. Restarted my PC entered into BIOS, selected the 'Boot Options' and here I'm not finding the 'Boot from USB/HDD' option.

Observed that my internal disks are in GTP partition scheme, read a post that USB should also be in same scheme, so tried to create USB image also in GTP scheme but Rufus wasn't giving me that option. Also, in Boot Options, there was an option 'Boot from EFI file...' through which I was able to see the USB detected and was able to browse files like a file explorer. No idea what to do with that, so left it there. Can anyone please help me in this tough situation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update: I have tried changing the boot priority to USB, but didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot) and [Which USB boot selection do I use?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770533/)

Comment: Why are you trying to install 16.04? It will lose support in 1 year.

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu 16.04 does not support UEFI, therefore, does not support GPT.**

It will also lose support in another year. So the best thing that you can do is use Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04.

See [How to create a bootable USB with Windows](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview).

You can use the same tutorial you have posted in the question. It tells you to use something else option but you can use install alongside windows option too.